# How to open the mjpg-streamer to the Internet?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have installed mjpg-streamer in my PC(ubuntu 11.01). now I can see the video when I get to 
 http://192.168.xxx.xxx:8080/?action=stream
I want to open the mjpg-streamer to the Internet,so that I can see the video from every computer on the Internet.What should I do? 
Any answers  will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The IP number suggests some kind of NAT situation. You need to set up port forwarding in the equipment that interfaces against "the internet" and your internal LAN. This way you get a port that is available to "the internet" that will be forwarded to your machine and people on "the internet" can view the stream.

Depending on your equipment and the streaming software that you use, you might also need to set up some kind of masquerading/source address rewrite for outgoing connections from your LAN to "the internet".